# delete a node from sitemap xml

Tags: c#, mvcsitemapprovider, xml-sitemap

I have sitemap format as below.
I want to delete a complete node that
I find loc.
For example:

Where a node has `<loc>`with a value of http://www.my.com/en/flight1.
I want to delete the `<url>` node and his child
I want to delete `loc`
than `lastmod` than `priority` and than `changefreq`

```
<url>
<loc>http://www.my.com/en/flight1
</loc>
<lastmod>2015-03-05</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<changefreq>never</changefreq>
</url>


<url>
<loc>
http://www.my.com/en/flight2
</loc>
<lastmod>2015-03-05</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<changefreq>never</changefreq>
</url>


<url>
<loc>
http://www.my.com/en/flight3
</loc>
<lastmod>2015-03-05</lastmod>
<priority>0.5</priority>
<changefreq>never</changefreq>
</url>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using C# you should use `System.xml.linq` (XDocument)

You can remove a node like so:

```
XDocument.Load(/*URI*/);

var elements = document.Root.Elements().Where(e => e.Element("loc") != null && e.Element("loc").Value == "http://www.my.com/en/flight1");
foreach (var url in elements)
{
    url.Remove();
}
```

Comment: this give error:  XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteMapXMLPath"]);   @cedric

Comment: SiteMapXM‌​LPath is path of this file :   http://yazilimsozluk.com/sitemap.xml       it give that error: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.     with this line:   XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SiteMapXMLPath"]);

Comment: Use XDocument.Load(uri) instead

Comment: this is url variable <url xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
  <loc>http://www.my.com/tr</loc>
  <lastmod>2014-02-02</lastmod>
  <priority>0.5</priority>
  <changefreq>never</changefreq>
</url>   but  url.Element("loc") is null  http://i.hizliresim.com/22PW9d.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/72354/discussion-between-cedric-and-user1688401).